# ie9 not displaying background image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I am facing very strange issue..

I've built this website:

[www.shtelzer.co.il](http://shtelzer.co.il)

for some reason, explorer 9 will not display background images,

for example, welcome block css properties:

```
.welcome-block {
    background-image: url('../images/welcomebg1024.jpg');
}
```

I tried everything: change source image, change it to png, svg, background-position, background-attachement...